# Select statement for Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, select

I have a table say,

```
column1 column2
a   apple
a   ball
a   boy
b   apple
b   eagle
b   orange
c   bat
c   ball
c   cork
```

Now I would like to fetch column1 based on the rows that doesn't contain 'apple' and also ignore values in column1 if any of the rows have 'apple' in it. So in the table above only 'C' must be retured.
I am kind of new to Oracle SQL and I know Select column1 from table where column2 != 'apple' will not work. I need some help with this please.

Comment: So you need to select only value of column1 in this case only `C` should be selected?

Comment: yes. thats right..@StanislovasKalašnikovas

Comment: What you have tried and what problem you are facing ?

Comment: `NOT EXISTS` is a good start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that `column1` is `NOT NULL` you could use:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t.column1
FROM table_name t
WHERE t.column1 NOT IN (SELECT column1
                        FROM table_name
                        WHERE column2 = 'apple');
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](http://rextester.com/IPI43321)**</kbd>

To get all columns and rows change `DISTINCT t.column1` to `*`.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `DISTINCT` with `NOT IN` in following:

**QUERY 1 using NOT IN**

```
select distinct col1
from t
where col1 not in (select col1 from t where col2 = 'Apple')
```

**QUERY 2 using NOT EXISTS**

As per @jarlh comment you could use `NOT EXISTS` in following:

```
select distinct col1
from #t t1
where not exists (select 1 from #t t2 where col2 = 'Apple' and t1.col1 = t2.col1)
```

**SAMPLE DATA**

```
create table t
(
    col1 nvarchar(60),
    col2 nvarchar(60)
)
insert into t values
('a','apple')
,('a','ball')
,('a','boy')
,('b','apple')
,('b','eagle')
,('b','orange')
,('c','bat')
,('c','ball')
,('c','cork')
```

Comment: I never recommend `NOT IN` because of the null behavior that many people find too surprising. `NOT EXISTS` is "null safe"

Comment: @jarlh updated my answer with your suggestion to use `NOT EXISTS`

Answer (score 0):

```
Select * from tbl
Left join (
    Select column1 from tbl
    Where column2 like '%apple%'
    Group by column1
    ) g on tbl.colum1 = g.column1
Where g.column1 is null
```

Seems to me that you need to find a summary of all colum1 values that have any reference to apple. Then list the rows that have no match to the summary list (g)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand well, you need the values af `column1` such that in your table does not exist a row with the same value of `column1` and `'apple'` in `column2`; you can translate this in SQL with:

```
Select column1
from your_table t
where not exists ( 
                   select 1
                   from your_table t2
                   where t2.column1 = t1.column1
                     and t2.column2= 'apple'
                 )
```

This is only one of the possible ways to get your result, soyou can rewrite it in many ways; I believe this way of writing is similar enough to the logics to clearly explain how a logic could be written in plain SQL.